# (Java/Mybatis) Failed to rollback at `catch` when cause exception(s)

Tags: java, mybatis

In my limited experience with **mybatis**.
I could NOT rollback all **SQL** that were executed in transaction.
I've tried multiple variations of this, but none of them seem to work. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

1. Set a Field with `varchar(4)` in DB (mysql).
2. Insert the Field with `"name"` and `"12345"`.
3. Insert `"name"` successfully (**No Rollback**).

PS:

1. This project was NOT working in `Spring`.
2. I need **throw this exception** and **keep data correct** which means rollback successfully.

```java
SqlSession sqlSession = MybatisKit.openSqlSession(false);
try {
    TestMapper testMapper = sqlSession.getMapper(TestMapper.class);
    // successfully
    testMapper.insert("name");
    // throw an exception: Data too long for column ...
    testMapper.insert("12345");

    sqlSession.commit();
 } catch (Throwable e) {
    sqlSession.rollback();
    // no leak
    sqlSession.close();

    throw new RuntimeException("asd");
}
sqlSession.close();
```

Comment: Are you sure that exception is thrown? mysql can be configured so that it does not throw exception, the value is truncated and execution continues. In this case no rollback happens obviously

Comment: @Roman Konoval 
Yeah, I am Sure. I am reproducing the situation. The `point` is that it can `NOT` be rollback if an exception is thrown, `NOT` this case. :p

Comment: If the exception happens then please include error message and the stacktrace to your question.

Comment: @Roman Konoval   Error message: `Data too long for column ...`  

I mean... emm.. NOT this case and error message, the `POINT` is that failed to rollback...

Comment: I need throw this exception and keep data correct which means rollback successfully...